# How can I add line breaks in an XML file from the Unix command line?

Tags: command-line, unix

I have a large XML file. From  the Unix command line, I'd like to add a newline after every `>`.

I have tried using sed for this, with no luck:

```
sed -i '' -e's/>/>\n/' file.xml
```

This just inserts the letter `n`, not a newline. I've also tried `\r` and `\r\n`.

How can I do this?

(FYI - I'm using zshell in OSX.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Script

Use `indentxml file.xml` to view, `indentxml file.xml > new.xml` to edit.

Where indentxml is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Purpose: Read an XML file and indent it for ease of reading
# Author:  RedGrittyBrick 2011. 
# Licence: Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
#
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" unless $filename;

open my $fh , '<', $filename
  or die "Can't read '$filename' because $!\n";
my $xml = '';
while (<$fh>) { $xml .= $_; }
close $fh;

$xml =~ s|>[\n\s]+<|><|gs;                       # remove superfluous whitespace
$xml =~ s|><|>\n<|gs;                            # split line at consecutive tags

my $indent = 0;
for my $line (split /\n/, $xml) {

  if ($line =~ m|^</|) { $indent--; }

  print '  'x$indent, $line, "\n";

  if ($line =~ m|^<[^/\?]|) { $indent++; }             # indent after <foo
  if ($line =~ m|^<[^/][^>]*>[^<]*</|) { $indent--; }  # but not <foo>..</foo>
  if ($line =~ m|^<[^/][^>]*/>|) { $indent--; }        # and not <foo/>

}
```

### Parser

Of course, the canonical answer is to use a proper XML parser.

```
# cat line.xml
<a><b>Bee</b><c>Sea</c><d><e>Eeeh!</e></d></a>

# perl -MXML::LibXML -e 'print XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("line.xml")->toString(1)'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <b>Bee</b>
  <c>Sea</c>
  <d>
    <e>Eeeh!</e>
  </d>
</a>
```

### Utility

But maybe the easiest is

```
# xmllint --format line.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <b>Bee</b>
  <c>Sea</c>
  <d>
    <e>Eeeh!</e>
  </d>
</a>
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about `xmllint`. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, as usual, any attempt parsing XML with regexps are futile. Never forget `<something attribute="<foo>">` is valid XML, string  type attributes may take any literal string as a value. http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-attribute-types

Comment: +1 for alerting me to the existence of xmllint! That solved my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no escape sequence, you need to literally use the newline character. So for this input

```
$ cat /tmp/example 
<this is one tag><this is another tag><here again>
```

You would have to use

```
$ sed -e 's_>_&\
_g' /tmp/example
```

which produces

```
<this is one tag>
<this is another tag>
<here again>
```

Note that the newline has to be escaped (as shown above)

Answer (score 0):

Your command works properly, just not enough.

Try adding the 'g' option to the end of the 's'ubstitute command to make sed examine ALL of the '>' characters in each line of the input file.

Use:

```
sed -i -e 's/>/>\n/g' file.xml
```

note the trailing 'g' on the substitute command.

the *suffix* part of the '-i' option is optional, and may be omitted.

The other answers given work nicely too, but your initial attempt was correct, albeit missing the 'g'lobal option.

Comment: On my OSX machine using zshell, that command converts `<foo><bar>stuff</bar></foo>` to `<foo>n<bar>nstuff</bar>n</foo>n`.

Comment: Hmmm, that means zsh is screwing with escaped characters within a SINGLE quoted string.  That's not good.  Single quotes are supposed to be untouched by interpretation by the shell.  I have not been able to reproduce this output myself, using your original command, perhaps something from your zsh environment is affecting quoted strings. I'd suggest looking at any startup scripts / customizations you've applied to your zsh shell.

Comment: After reading your comment, I tried this with both single and double quotes from zsh, then I switched to bash and tried both ways. In every case, it just inserted `n`. I'm using OSX Snow Leopard - what are you using?

Comment: Oh, that's likely the big issue, I'm using linux, you've got the OSX tweaked sed.  hmm.  Stupid things to try: double the backslash (\\n), try \r (or \\r) for mac style line endings (shouldn't matter, \n is universal). Try it with perl:   perl -i -e 's/>/>\n/g' xxx.xml     Perl might work, pretty much the same cmd line options.  can do multiple files if you add the '-p' option too.   Frustrating that a low-level app like sed doesn't operate as expected though.  Maybe there's an option to turn off 'pooh-headed tweaks because we can' or something.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `xmllint --format` which will reformat exactly that way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).